# Google Calendar Script to create event with GuestsCanModify set to true?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have managed to get a script working to to take values form a google spreadsheet and create calendar events.  I can add guests but I can't figure out how to allow them guest can modify status.  I can set advanced arguments like location and guests. How do I set this on an event as I create it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is [CalendarEvent.setGuestsCanModify()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setGuestsCanModify%28Boolean%29).

```
  ....
  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
  });

  event.setGuestsCanModify(true);
  ....
```