# How to add editor in your event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

i want to create event and add editing rights for one person in it, i know how to add guests:

```
event.addGuest("guest email");
```

you can add edditor in spredsheet:

```
sheet.addEditor("editor email")
```

can you do something same for event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Calendar doesn't use the term "editors", the details are explained on the [Sharing and Attendees](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/sharing) section of the Google Calendar API documentation. In summary, to allow others to edit your event but not give this privilege to all the event guests, you have to create a calendar, share it with the "editors" and give the permissions to edit the events.

In order to be able to handle the Google Calendar Sharing features you might use [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar?hl=en) or access the Google Calendar API by using the Fetch Service (UrlFetchApp).

Related

- [Google Calendar Script to create event with GuestsCanModify set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18918286/1595451)
- [Sharing a Calendar in Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27094575/1595451)

Comment: thank you, can you also say if there is a way to add role after you created? or you can do it only when create event?

Comment: @DragonHunter You are welcome. Do you already read the first link?

Comment: yes, but there is no examples, so i understand how roles works, but not how to make them, i saw example with using role inside of event creation but i need to make it separately

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question.

Comment: will creating new post with my code will help? it uses data from spredsheet and im not sharing it

Comment: Be sure that the code included in the question is a [mcve].