# How to add someone with abillity to eddit events in callendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

This is my code:

```
    var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("callendar id").createEvent(
  "title",
  "datetime of starting event", 
  "datetime of ending event");
        for (var a = 1; a <= editor.length; a++)
        {
          if (editor === editor[a-1][1])
          {      
            event.addGuest(editor [a-1][0]);
            //i want editing parameter here
          }
        }  
        for (var j = 1; j <= grupav.length; j++)  
        {
          Logger.log(grupav [j-1][0])
          event.addGuest(grupav [j-1][0]);
        }
      }
```

`editor` and `gropav` are Arrays with emails, first would be people who allowed to be editors and second is readers without right to edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign role"? P.S. In order to have a good [mcve] you might want to add some sample data for `data`, `editor` and `grupvav` or just make a [mcve] that handles a single event including representative *hardcoded* values.

Comment: @Rubén is this better?

Comment: Still is not completely clear what you mean by "assign role", anyway, I assumed that you mean calendar access role. Please checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "role" you are referring to the **access roles** depicted in [Sharing and Attendees](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/sharing), those belongs to the Sharing Calendars section, meaning that they are assigned to calendars, not to events.

If you want to allow someone to edit the event you have to share the calendar with them and assign them the writer access role. [Mogsdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27110258/1595451) to a previous question   has an example of how to share a calendar using Google Apps Script. Please note that Mogsdad's code uses **Advanced Calendar Service**. If you aren't familiar with this service, please read the links in the resources section of this answer.

The way that you might use the Mogsdad's `shareCalendar` function could be this:

```
let rule = shareCalendar( 'gobbledygook@group.calendar.google.com',
               editor [a-1][0],
               'writer' );
```

Related

- [Google Calendar Script to create event with GuestsCanModify set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18918286/1595451)
- [Sharing a Calendar in Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27094575/1595451)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar

Comment: should it be something like this?
 var rule = shareCalendar("calendar id",editor [a-1][0]).role = "writer";
i dont realy understand Mogsdad's answer to be honnest, its hard to read for me

Comment: It looks that you missed to add the the shareCalendar function declaration. Don't forget to enable the Advanced Calendar Service and to add the corresponding code to use the create / update the rule.

Comment: you suggest me to use function that Mogsdad did?

Comment: Only if you are able to understand how it works and how to use it.

Comment: It's very likely that you should start by learning how to use the Advanced Calendar Service.

Comment: i dont understand, so, basicaly you said that i can add people to calendar and asing role in it? every user that you invite is default as a reader, but what function makes user an editor? or there is no such function?

Comment: On the my answer to your previous question  and in this one I said that there it's not possible to add an editor to a single event, in other words, "there is no such function".

Comment: sorry, to clarify, i understand it, and i want to add editor to whole calendar, how i can do it?

Comment: First you have to learn how to use the Advanced Calendar Service. If you already know that, please post a new question showing what you tried as a [mcve].

Comment: sorry for asking again, to clarify, there is no function or parameter that allow me to give people creator rights to calendar?